# Permutation with repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

Find number of ways to place 10 books: 4 from biology,3 math and 3 chemistry, so that book from biology is first from left. Just want to check is the right answer:$4\frac{9!}{(3!)^3}$

Answer (score 0):

There are $3$ subjects so there are $3!$ choices for the subject. Since there are $4$ biology books, there are $4!$ ways to arrange, similarly there are $2.3!$ ways to arrange math and chemistry book. So in total there are $3!. 4! . 2.3!$ ways = $1728$ ways of arranging them on shelf.

Comment: Why i can't fix one book of biology first from left, and to choose it on 4 ways. Then for the rest 3 book from biology, 3 from math and 3 from chemistry we have $\frac{9!}{(3!)^3}$ since those are permutation with repetitions.

Comment: Doesn't the question says that biology books are from left? That is we order first biology book, then second, then third and then fourth? Then we can choose any of books from math or chemistry? (I'm assuming that books are distinct). Or maybe I misunderstood it! Sorry if I did

Comment: All books from biology, math and chemistry are same. And it is said that only one book from biology is from the left.